# How to remove aws-cdk properly?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terminal, aws-cdk

I need to remove aws-cdk properly.

I have installed it with this command :

```
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

But if I use :

```
npm uninstall -g aws-cdk
```

it's not clean. It's remove some packages not all. need to purge all packages.

Do you have a clean command, please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove aws-cdk and all of its dependencies, you can use the following command:

```
npm uninstall -g aws-cdk && npm cache clean --force
```

This command will not only uninstall the aws-cdk package, but it will also clean the npm cache to remove any remaining files and dependencies.

After running this command, you can confirm that the aws-cdk and its dependencies have been fully removed by checking the global npm directory for any remaining packages. You can do this by running:

```
npm ls -g aws-cdk
```

If there are no remaining aws-cdk files or directories listed in the output, then the aws-cdk and all of its dependencies have been successfully removed from your system.